# Keep script variables in scope when loading from irb

Tags: python, ruby, ipython, irb

When I execute a script in IPython, by using `run myscript.py`, the names from the script are then available in the interactive interpreter for me to experiment with further.

In `irb` this doesn't seem to happen when I run the script using `load 'myscript.rb'`.

How do I keep the variables in scope in interactive ruby?

Comment: which verion of ruby you are using? and can you be specific to your requirement?

Comment: wim@wim-desktop:~$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
wim@wim-desktop:~$ irb --version
irb 0.9.5(05/04/13)

Answer (score 2):

Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in. That's why they are called *local* variables. If you define a local variable in the script `myscript.rb`, then it will be defined inside that scope and *nowhere else*. That's the whole point of local variables.

If you want a variable that is available globally, use a global variable. Or maybe an instance variable of the top-level `main` object.

Comment: I don't understand, if I have a file `foo.py` with just the line `s = 'hello world'` in it, that is a global variable.  If I rename the file to `foo.rb` it's now a local variable??

Comment: Yes, it is. Because you are talking about two completely unrelated programming languages which have absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with each other. They have different syntax, different semantics, a different type system, a different object system. `s` is *never* a global variable in Ruby. In Ruby, global variables *always* start with a `$` sign.

Comment: OK, fair enough, so is there any way to run my ruby script which is bringing names into scope in irb?

Comment: I just found I could get what I was looking for with a glorified copy and paste using `eval File.read('foo.rb')`

Comment: Yes, that works in Ruby 1.8, because `eval` leaks its scope. However, that bug was fixed in Ruby 1.9.

Comment: I'm un-accepting this answer because, whilst it's a clear explanation, it doesn't really solve my problem.  I want to experiment with variables defined in a script from within irb, without needing to modify them into global variables.

Answer (score 1):

The answer I found while looking that this problem was to use a global variable or a class or function.

So for example, if I am using `watir` and I have a browser object I am interacting with, I can get it out of a test script with the following:

### Global Variables

watir_test.rb

```
require "watir-webdriver"

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
$b = browser

# all sorts of preliminary stuff I do on the browser object

# end of my test script
```

Now after launching `irb`, I load the test file

```
irb(main):001:0> load './watir_test.rb'
irb(main):002:0> browser
NameError: undefined local variable or method `browser' for main:Object
    from (irb):2
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):004:0> $b
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x..fd9200f9a url="http....">
```

### Returned Element(s)

```
test_code.rb

    def test_code
        a = 5    
        return a
    end

> load 'test_code.rb'
> a = test_code()
```

### Return + local_variables

Here is a neat example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1961317/999943

[Ruby local_variables returns :symbols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618230/ruby-local-variables-returns-symbols)

```
def foo(((a, b, c, d), e, *f), g, *h)
  local_variables.sort.each do |lvar| puts "#{lvar} => #{eval(lvar).inspect}" end
end

foo([[1, 2, 3], 4, 5, 6], 7, 8, 9)
# a => 1
# b => 2
# c => 3
# d => nil
# e => 4
# f => [5, 6]
# g => 7
# h => [8, 9]
```