# Ruby local_variables returns :symbols?

Tags: ruby, local-variables

I was looking through the ruby Kernel doc and saw this method:

```
a = 2
local_variables # => [:a, :_]
```

Why does it return :a and not a?
I thought the ":" was reserved for symbols, but the symbol :a doesn't point to the variable a nor to it's assigned value, 2.

Furthermore, how would I go about accessing the actual variables through this method? As in b=local_variables.first (would be 2, but is :a).

Is there a reason behind this behavior, what is it?

Thanks/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does it return :a and not a? I thought the ":" was reserved for symbols

It's the expected behavior. According to the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-local_variables):

> Returns the **names** of the current local variables.

So yes, this just returns an array of symbols.

---

> Furthermore, how would I go about accessing the actual variables through this method?

As noted by Jonathan Camenisch, Ruby 2.1 introduced [`Binding#local_variable_get`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get):

```
a = 2
binding.local_variable_get(:a)
#=> 2
```

For older Rubies, you could use `eval`:

```
a = 2
eval(:a.to_s)
#=> 2
```

---

> Is there a reason behind this behavior, what is it?

In Ruby symbols are used for references:

```
"foo".methods
#=> [:<=>, :==, :===, :eql?, :hash, :casecmp, ...]

Module.constants
#=> [:Object, :Module, :Class, :BasicObject, :Kernel, :NilClass, ...]
```

Comment: Rather than `eval (:a.to_s)`, you could use `binding.local_variable_get(:a)`. So to list all inputs or local variables:

`def show_inputs(a, b, c)`
  `Hash[local_variables.map { |name| [name, binding.local_variable_get(name)] }]`
`end`
`show_inputs('one', 'two', 'three')`
`#=> {:a=>"one", :b=>"two", :c=>"three"}`

Comment: So, that doesn't work very well. Here's what I meant that to look like: https://gist.github.com/jcamenisch/f7a3daee296e619086c9

Answer (score 3):

> Why does it return :a and not a?

It can't return `a`, because `a` is a variable and variables aren't objects in Ruby. Methods can only take, return, and manipulate objects.

Answer (score 1):

> how would I go about accessing the actual variables through this method?

Humm.here you can go:-

```
a = 2
b = 10
local_variables.each{|e| p eval(e.to_s)}
# >> 2
# >> 10
```

---

> Why does it return :a and not a?

That answer has been given by **@Stefan**. But you can get here some more taste:-

[**`13 Ways of Looking at a Ruby Symbol`**](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/01/20/13-ways-of-looking-at-a-ruby-symbol#7)

Out of these the below is related to your answer:-

***7. A Ruby symbol is a Ruby identifier***

In Ruby, we can look up identifiers (variable, methods and constant names) while the program is running. This is typically done using symbols.

```
class Demo
  # The stuff we'll look up.
  DEFAULT = "Hello"
  def initialize
    @message = DEFAULT
  end
  def say() @message end

  # Use symbols to look up identifiers.
  def look_up_with_symbols
    [Demo.const_get(:DEFAULT),
     method(:say),
     instance_variable_get(:@message)]
  end
end

Demo.new.look_up_with_symbols
```

Comment: Thanks for that link too, it helped a lot